# Biholomorphic mobius transformations preserving hyperbolic distances on the poincare disk

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation

On wikipedia it says that mobius transformations of the form $$f(z)=e^{i\phi}\frac{z+b}{\bar{b}z+1}$$ where $b\in\mathbb{C},|b|<1$ and $\phi\in\mathbb{R}$ is a biholomprhic map $D\rightarrow D$, but also that "By introducing a suitable metric, the open disk turns into another model of the hyperbolic plane, the Poincaré disk model, and this group is the group of all orientation-preserving isometries of $H^2$ in this model." There doesn't seem to be a citation of the fact about the poincare disk, so I am confused as to how to prove this is the case.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation

Answer (score 0):

For references, I can recommend [this webpage](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Abstract_and_Geometric_Algebra/Introduction_to_Groups_and_Geometries_(Lyons)/03%3A_Geometries/3.03%3A_Hyperbolic_geometry) or if you need a book, I really like the first chapter of Katok's [Fuchsian groups](https://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/F/bo3621076.html).

From the webpage:

**Proposition 3.3.3:**
A Mobius transformation preserves the Disk if and only if it is of the above form.

Distance $d$ is defined in Formula (3.3.3).

**Proposition 3.3.13:** The Mobius transformation of the above form are isometries.

**Proposition 3.3.15:**
$d$ is a distance.

Definition 3.3.22 is about the upper halfplane model.

A concrete way of going from the unit disk to the upper halfplane model is given by the Cayley-transformation
$$
f(z) = \frac{z +i}{iz+1}
$$
whose formula is also given in the Wikipedia article you linked. You can use $f$ to get the distance from one model to the other.

Do you need more?

Comment: Thank you. This should hopefully be enough for now.